# i3 messed up after Ubuntu update

Tags: package-management, debug, i3-window-manager

So after updating my packages today, i3 is messed up. As far as I can tell all my config files are still in the correct place / present, I am not sure why and what on gods green earth is happening. Can't find anything in i3 error logs.

None of my hotkeys work, in fact no keys seem to work at all. The bar does get loaded with the correct fonts but appears at the bottom of the screen instead of top as specified, the background does not get changed by the `~/.i3/config` script (with feh), making me believe that it is no longer being called. The bar may be called by the default and load the bar's presets. Why?

I'm not sure what more detail to provide. Here is [.i3/config](https://github.com/ZirconCode/config/blob/master/.i3/config), [i3 status config](https://github.com/ZirconCode/config/blob/master/i3status/config).

What can I do to fix this and prevent it from ever wasting my time again? Is it recommended to avoid installing i3 from the package manager?

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html).

Comment: found and fixed the problem, although not sure why the config load order was changed

Answer (score 0):

I had an old/default config file at `~/.config/i3/config` as well and somehow the priority of loading changed during the update. Deleted it, fixed.

`i3 --moreversion | grep config` may be of debugging help for others in similar cases.